# The project needs to be deployed before it can be started remote debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging, windows-rt

i'm trying to remote debug my windows tablet store app and when i go to debug it on the remote machine i get this error.

[image]

i have done both ways it asks me to fix it in the image but i keep getting the same result. the tablet has the remote manager installed on it with the update version downloaded from Microsoft.

Comment: If you deploy your app under Build->Deploy manually just in local machine, how about the result? Do you get any detailed messages in the output window? I met this error which is related to the platformTarget(X86/ANY CPU) or it has been installed in one machine before. You could check it in your side.

Comment: Thanks, i deployed it to my local machine and received this error "Registration of the app failed. An internal error occurred with error 0x80073D05.". After a bit of googling i found out that i needed to uninstall the app from my local machine and simulator. Once i removed that i ran again and still got the issue. After a bit more googling i found that you need to remove the install package stored at C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Packages\. Deleted the folder ran locally and all worked. i have yet to try this with the remote debugger as I'm out of the office atm but will post results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled the app installation folders on the remote machine and received a different issue. " Could not generate the root folder for app, Illegal characters in path. "

answer was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699119/vs2015-sp3-remote-debug-illegal-characters-in-path)

Comment: Glad to know that it has been resolved, you could mark it as the answer:)