# VS2015 remote debug illegal characters in path

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I have issue to deploy UWP app on Windows IoT (on raspberri pi2 device) :

> Error DEP4300 : Could not generate the root folder for app package xxx|VS.Debug_x86.xxx|CN=xx|xxxxxx.Debug_x86.xxx with base layout folder of C:\Users\xxxx. Illegal characters in path.

Windows 10 IoT version: 10.0.10586
VS 2015 SP3

Thanks

Comment: Have you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699119/vs2015-sp3-remote-debug-illegal-characters-in-path)?

Comment: Yes, but how to update the remote debugger on Windows 10 IoT? I tried to click on the "Check for updates" button in "Windows update" page of the device portal but it seems this does not work.

Comment: You can re-flash SD card with newer Windows iot core using [IoT Dashboard](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/iotdashboard).

Comment: Okay. Thanks for help. I will test that you suggest as soon as possible and I will post a feedback here.

Comment: Hi @RitaHan-MSFT, it works for me. But it is a strange way to make updates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the solution, in the comment of Rita Han, which is to flash the sd card with the newer Windows IoT core.
See the  following link:

[IoT Dashboard](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/iotdashboard)